# BizTalk Mapping

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I need to convert the input XML to output as shown below

### Input

```
<root>
          <MOD_FACTOR>10</MOD_FACTOR>
          <X_MOD_FACTOR>20</X_MOD_FACTOR>
</root>

Ouput
------
<root>
          <Data>
                   <Name> MOD_FACTOR</Name>
                   <Value>10</Value>
          </Data>
<Data>
                    <Name>X_MOD_FACTOR</Name>
                   <Value>20</Value>
          </Data>
</root>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the "Looping functoid" examples. They show a very similar problem.